# Generate PPM signal using javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to manipulate radio control servos using the headphone port.
For this I would need to generate a PPM signal through the headphone/speaker output.

I am thinking of using the tone oscillator found here http://www.softsynth.com/webaudio/tone.php

Am I on the right track?

Detail of PPM signal http://www.mftech.de/ppm_en.htm

Any advice welcome TQ

Comment: Wow, controlling digital servos using audio ports… that I call a hack. Yes, the webaudio API is the way to go if you need to control this from the browser.

Comment: TQ Bergi - steep learn curve on this project (FYI am trying to copy this https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/flypad-buddy-box-for-ios/id375967752?mt=8)